# Security issues after upgrading to Spring 3.2.8

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, openfaces

I recently upgraded from spring 3.0 to spring 3.2.8 and after that a servlet creating a pdf (jasper) crash giving security error messages.

My Spring config:

```
<security:http auto-config="true"> 
    <security:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler" login-page="/login.faces" login-processing-url="/loginProcess" authentication-failure-url="/login.faces?login_error=1" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.faces" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/images/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/css/main.css" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/css/login.css" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout.faces" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/rest/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/openFacesResources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/primefaces_resource/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/module/dsl/binding-def/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/module/dsl/validation" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_AUTHENTICATED" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/webservice/ddiGenerator" access="ROLE_AUTHENTICATED"/>
    <security:logout logout-url="/logoutProcess" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>
</security:http>
```

---

Below stack error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception
    at org.openfaces.util.ResourceFilter.doFilter(ResourceFilter.java:105)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:232)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Doesn't look like a security error message. Most likely something is messed up with your classpath. Check the jars in your app for duplicates, missing jars or incorrect versions.

Comment: That's my jar version list:
org.springframework.version 3.2.8.RELEASE
org.springframework.security.version 3.2.1.RELEASE
org.hibernate.core.version 3.5.3-Final
org.hibernate.annotation.version 3.5.3-Final
org.hibernate.validator.version 4.1.0.Final
slf4j.version 1.5.6
org.springframework.swf.version 2.0.9.RELEASE
net.sf.jasperreports 4.0.1
org.openfaces 2.0
prettyfaces-jsf12 3.1.0

Comment: facelets-taglib-jsf12-spring-3-0.4.jar

Comment: SOLVED: Thanks Luke. You were right I was missing the spring-context-support jar